# Which functions have growth rates between $\log n$ and $n$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Is there any function with a rate of growth between $n$ and $\log(n)$?

My problem is that I have a value $x$, against which a term varies. The term does not vary as rapidly a linear function of $x$ but not as slowly as $log(x)$ (Choosing a different base of log can't help as for larger n the change in the function will still only happen for an large (exponential) increase).

How to model that function $f(x)$?

Comment: For sure, for any $n\geq 3$ we have $\log(n)<\sqrt{n}< \sqrt{n \log n}< n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log{n}$ grows more slowly than any positive power of $n$, so $n^{1/2}$, $n^{2/3}$, $n^{1/\pi}$ are all possibilities. You really need a more concrete idea of the growth to work out which applies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. you are right, I need to figure out the growth.

Answer (score 2):

The function $(\log n)^{\alpha}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{(\log n)^{\alpha}} = 0 \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^{\alpha}}{n} = 0$$
for $\alpha > 1$. (Showing the first limit is straightforward---for the second, just apply L'Hôpital's Rule once.)

Comment: For the second one,  $(\log n)^a/n=((\log n)/n^{1/a})^a=$ $((\log (n^{1/a})/n^{1/a})^a\cdot (a^a)=$ $((\log m)/m)^a\cdot a^a$ with $m=n^{1/a}.$ Since $m\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\log x)/x=0,$ we are done...............+1

Answer (score 0):

The function which gives the $x$-th Harmonic Number, $H_x = \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$ approaches $\ln x + \gamma$ for very large $x$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, ~$.577...$. No rational function is asymptotic to $\ln x$ because all rational functions are asymptotix to $x^k$ for some integer $k$, is that what you're after? If you just want a function that grows less than $y=x$ but more than $\ln x$, this would be satisfied by $y=x^{1/n}$ for any $n \gt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The ladder generally chosen to express growth is $n^\alpha\ln(n)^\beta\ln(\ln(n))^\gamma\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))^\delta...$ and so on, with iterated logarithms.

And on the other side, for functions growing faster than any power of n, you can also combine with iterated exponentials $e^n$,$e^{e^n}$,$e^{e^{e^n}}$,...

But there are also things that are not in this ladder, for instance $n^n$, $n^{\ln n}$, $(\ln n)^{\sqrt n}$ and any monster you can think about.

So it is difficult to establish an universal growth ladder.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $g(x)>0$  for all sufficiently large $x$ and suppose  $g(x)/f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$  For $a\in (0,1)$ let $h_a(x)=f(x)^ag(x)^{1-a}$ whenever $ f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$.

Then $h_a(x)/f(x)=(g(x)/f(x))^{1-a} \to 0$ and $g(x)/h_a(x)=(g(x)/f(x))^a  \to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$ In your Q let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\log x.$